# Dynamic table over multiple pages when generating pdf with apache pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I built an electron app that creates a calendar document. Right now the generation of the pdf is done within the browser. I would want to bring the application into the web and, I want to do the pdf generation in the backend. Techstack: Kotlin, Spring, Vue

I want to use the apache pdf box for the pdf generation. But, I'm struggling with the generation of the dynamic table. It is all about events that happen on a specific date. I have drawn an example with 10 Events.

As example,
Event 1 will happen on 01.01.2021

2 on 03.01.2021

9 on 27.01.2021

10 on 29.01.2021

[image: Example]

Depending on the number of events the 2 columns can span over multiple pages. I couldn't find out if this is possible with the apache pdf box. Maybe someone can help or if another lib is better. I would be also happy with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pdfbox itself does not provide layout features, you have to calculate positions for your contents yourself. There are some libraries by other parties providing some layout features using pdfbox underneath. I don't know, though, whether they support your requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to share some three documents which are currently created in the browser?